# Look for words in strings with LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

> C# or VB.NET suggestion are welcome.

I have the following code:

```
 Dim someText = "Stack Over Flow Community"
    Dim someWord = "Over Community"

    If someText.Contains(someWord) Then
        Response.Write("Word found.")
    Else
        Response.Write("No word found.")
    End If


 Function Contains looks only for next words from left to right. 

someText.Contains("Over Stack")  returns False
someText.Contains("Stack Community")  returns False
```

I want all of these to return True as long as there are words that exist in the string.

Is there any existing function that cover any case regardless of words position in the string?

Comment: Part of the problem is you are looking for a specific string that doesn't exist. You aren't looking for "Over" or "Stack", you are looking for "Over Stack". You can match a single word at a time or you can match an EXACT string. You'll have to split the strings you want to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
words.Split(' ').Any(someText.Contains)
```

Comment: Method group conversion allows you to omit the argument and just write `All(s.Contains)`.

Answer (score 4):

`someText.Split(' ').Intersect(someWord.Split(' ')).Any();`

Comment: Mine returns true if any word exists in the text, @Snowbear's returns it when all do. @Snowbear's is probably better since it doesn't also split the someText.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsWord(this string source, string contain)
    {
        List<string> sourceList = source.Split(' ').ToList();
        List<string> containList = contain.Split(' ').ToList();

        return sourceList.Intersect(containList).Any();
    }
}


string someText = "Stack Over Flow Community";
var res = someText.ContainsWord("Over Stack");          // return true
var res1 = someText.ContainsWord("Stack Community");    // return true
var res2 = someText.ContainsWord("Stack1 Community");   // return false
```

Comment: Split returns an array (that LINQ can query), is there a reason to make it a list?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Linq solutions would be an extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsAllWords(this string input, string search)
{
    foreach (string word in search.split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        if (!input.Contains(word))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
string test = "stack overflow";
string searchPhrase = "overflow stack";
Console.WriteLine(test.ContainsAllWords(searchPhrase));
```

Better for re-usability and makes your code more declarative (imho).